# Как найти компилятору main?

Tags: java

> 123@qwe-Vostro-5468:~$ java Red.class Error: Could not find or load
>   main class Red.class 123@qwe-Vostro-5468:~$ javac Red.java
>
> 123@qwe-Vostro-5468:~$ java Red.class Error: Could not find or load
>   main class Red.class

А вот собственно мой код который лежит в Red.java :

```
public class Red {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    while (x<2){        
    System.out.println("Doo");
    System.out.println("Bee");
    x = x + 1;
    }
    if (x == 1)
    System.out.println("Do");
}           
}
```

Comment: Manifest покажите

Comment: javac 1.8.0_111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо вызвать `java Red`, а не `java Red.class`, потому что в таком случае компилятор будет искать класс с именем *Red.class*